# How to obtain a formula for $f(z)$ given this recurrence

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

I am trying to figure out how to derive a formula for $f(z)$ that is a function of $z$ and maybe $k \in \mathbb{N}$:

$$
f(z) = 1+z f \bigg(\frac{z}{1+z} \bigg)
$$

As an attempt, I tried a change of variable $z=\frac{1}{x}$, and I get:

$$
f\bigg(\frac{1}{x}\bigg) = 1 + \frac{1}{x}f\bigg(\frac{1/x}{1+1/x}\bigg)
$$

which evaluates to the following after simplifying the terms inside $f$:

$$
f\bigg(\frac{1}{x}\bigg) = 1 + \frac{1}{x}f\bigg(\frac{1}{1+x}\bigg)
$$

Now, given the above, is the following telescoping operation valid?

$$
f\bigg(\frac{1}{x}\bigg) = 1 + \frac{1}{x}\bigg[ 1 + \frac{1}{x} + f\bigg(\frac{1}{2+x}\bigg) \bigg] = 1 + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{(x+1)^2} + ... + \frac{1}{(x+k-3)^{k-2}} + \frac{1}{(x+k-2)^{k-1}}f\bigg(\frac{1}{k+x}\bigg)
$$

Also, how do I transform the above to a solution for $f(z)$?

Comment: No such function exists; try plugging $z = 0$ into your functional equation.

Comment: okay, i edited the question, i looked into the reference, and its initial condition is blank..

Comment: Also, shouldn't there be a $\frac{1}{x^{k-1}}$ factor out the front of $f(1/(k + x))$? There's also a $+$ that should be $\times$ in there.

Comment: @user759562, oh right, you got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we plug in $z=0$ to the original functional equation we get $f(0)=1$. Then we set $g(x)=f(1/x)$. We have, as you showed, that $$g(x)=1+\frac1{x}g(x+1).$$
Thus for integer $m>0$ we have
$$g(x)=g(x+m+1)\prod_{r=0}^{m}\frac1{x+r}+\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\prod_{j=0}^{k}\frac1{x+j}.$$
Taking the limit as $m\to\infty$ on both sides, we have $$g(x)=\sum_{k\ge0}\prod_{j=0}^{k}\frac1{x+j},$$
because $\lim_{m\to\infty}g(x+m)=\lim_{m\to\infty}f(\tfrac1{x+m})=f(\lim_{m\to\infty}\tfrac1{x+m})=f(0)=1$, while $\prod_{k\ge0}\frac1{x+k}=0$ for all $x\in\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Z_{\le 0}$. Thus  we have
$$f(x)=\sum_{k\ge0}\prod_{j=0}^{k}\frac1{1/x+j}.$$

Answer (score 1):

In the last step you plug $1+x$ in the place of $x$, hence you should have 
$$ f\left( \frac{1}{x}\right) = 1 + \frac{1}{x}f\left( \frac{1}{1+x}\right) = $$
$$ 1 + \frac{1}{x}\left[ 1 + \frac{1}{1+x}f\left( \frac{1}{2+x} \right)\right]$$

So I think the telescopic series you achieved isn't correct.